# published vite vue 3 npm package have problem with styles

Tags: typescript, npm, vuejs3, vite

I have published very simple toast component package in npm  , [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-toast-notification) with **vite** , **vue 3** and **typescript** .

you can see Repo [here](https://github.com/morteza-mortezai/vue-3-toast-notofication) .

there are **two** problems .

first problem is that when you install this package , styles doesn't apply

I can see style.css file in node-modules/my-package/dist/style.css But it can't be imported .

How can I fix this ?

Another problem is that when I try to **import** installed package component like this

```
import { ToastNot } from 'vue3-toast-notification';
```

I get **Typescript** error  .

[image]

How can I **fix** this to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vite Vue 3 library build doesn't implicitly include dist/style.css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72555787/vite-vue-3-library-build-doesnt-implicitly-include-dist-style-css)

Comment: no.............................